# Is there a way to make an embedded scope not inherit the general syntax highlighting in textmate

Tags: visual-studio-code, token, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I want to support embedding OCaml code inside HTML.
The embedded OCaml starts with the tag `<%` and closes with `%>`.
Inside these tags, we want everything to use the syntax of `source.ocaml`.
To do this, we use the following rules:

```
  "patterns": [
    {
      "begin": "(^|\\G)\\s*(<!--)",
      "captures": {
        "1": {
          "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.html"
        },
        "2": {
          "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.html"
        }
      },
      "end": "(-->)",
      "name": "comment.block.html"
    },
    {
      "begin": "(?i)(^|\\G)\\s*(?=<(script|style|pre)(\\s|$|>)(?!.*?</(script|style|pre)>))",
      "end": "(?i)(.*)((</)(script|style|pre)(>))",
      "endCaptures": {
        "1": {
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "text.html.derivative"
            }
          ]
        },
        "2": {
          "name": "meta.tag.structure.$4.end.html"
        },
        "3": {
          "name": "punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html"
        },
        "4": {
          "name": "entity.name.tag.html"
        },
        "5": {
          "name": "punctuation.definition.tag.end.html"
        }
      },
      "patterns": [
        {
          "begin": "(\\s*|$)",
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "text.html.derivative"
            }
          ],
          "while": "(?i)^(?!.*</(script|style|pre)>)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "begin": "(?i)(^|\\G)\\s*(?=</?[a-zA-Z]+[^\\s/&gt;]*(\\s|$|/?>))",
      "patterns": [
        {
          "include": "text.ocaml"
        }
        {
          "include": "text.html.derivative"
        }
      ],
      "while": "^(?!\\s*$)"
    },
    {
      "begin": "(^|\\G)\\s*(?=(<[a-zA-Z0-9\\-](/?>|\\s.*?>)|</[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]>)\\s*$)",
      "patterns": [
        {
          "include": "text.ocaml"
        },
        {
          "include": "text.html.derivative"
        }
      ],
      "while": "^(?!\\s*$)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `text.ocaml` looks likes this:

```
{
  "name": "Embedded Ocaml",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "name": "source.ocaml.embedded",
      "match": "(?<=<%)(.+)?(?=%>)",
      "captures": {
        "0": {
          "name": "source.ocaml",
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "source.ocaml"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scopeName": "text.ocaml"
}
```

This works fine if the tags are in between HTML tags, however, if the embedding tags are inside of an HTML string attribute, the embedded code inherits both the OCaml and HTML syntax highlighting.
So tokens that have a rule in the OCaml syntax are highlighted properly, but all the others are highlighted as HTML strings.
Is there a way to make the embedded scope NOT inherit the HTML syntax highlighting?[Here's a screenshot of what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lJy2.png)